# SQL Elastic Pools: "The semaphore timeout period has expired" while REBUILD index

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure, shrink

I'm shrinking databases that are already on a SQL Elastic Pool.

The goal is to fit as much as possible databases in a unique Elastic Pool.

In order to do so I've stubble upon a [blog](https://depretto.dev/troubleshooting/2022/02/08/dbcc-shrinkdatabase-is-not-working-oh-my-azure.html) that suggest to run this query which basically does 3 things:

1. -- Step 1: Rebuild all the indexes
2. -- Step 2: Shrink the database
3. -- Step 3: Rebuild all the indexes

Here comes the query:

```
create or alter procedure [#ForEachTable](@inputStmt nvarchar(max))
as
begin
    set nocount, xact_abort on;
    drop table if exists [#Tables];

    select concat(quotename([S].[name]), N'.', quotename([T].[name])) as [table]
    into [#Tables]
    from [sys].[schemas] as [S]
        inner join [sys].[tables] as [T]
            on [S].[schema_id] = [T].[schema_id]
    where [T].[is_ms_shipped] = 0;

    declare tables cursor local fast_forward for select [table] from [#Tables];
    open tables;

    declare @table nvarchar(max);
    fetch next from tables into @table;

    declare @total integer = (select count(*) from [#Tables]);
    declare @space integer = len(cast(@total as nvarchar(max)));
    declare @current integer = 1;
    while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin
        declare @stmt nvarchar(max) = replace(@inputStmt, N'?', @table);
        
        declare @msg nvarchar(max) = concat(
            sysutcdatetime(), N' - ',
            N'[', right(concat(N'000', @current), @space), N'/', @total, N']: ',
            N'Executing command: "', @stmt, N'".'
        );
        raiserror(@msg, 10, 1) with nowait;

        execute [sys].[sp_executesql] @stmt = @stmt;
    
        fetch next from tables into @table;
        set @current += 1;
    end;

    close tables;
    deallocate tables;
end;
go

-- Step 1: Rebuild all the indexes
raiserror(N'First rebuild...', 10, 1) with nowait;
execute [#ForEachTable] N'alter index all on ? rebuild with (online = on);';
go

-- Step 2: Shrink the database
raiserror(N'Shrink...', 10, 1) with nowait;
declare @stmt nvarchar(max) = concat(N'dbcc shrinkdatabase (', db_id(), N')');
execute [sys].[sp_executesql] @stmt = @stmt;
go

-- Step 3: Rebuild all the indexes
raiserror(N'Final rebuild...', 10, 1) with nowait;
execute [#ForEachTable] N'alter index all on ? rebuild with (online = on);';
```

But after sever hours I receive this warning message and then SSMS shut down:

```
First rebuild...
2023-06-06 07:39:50.2128129 - [0001/1467]: Executing command: "alter index all on [dbo].[xhisto_2018] rebuild with (online = on);".
2023-06-06 07:39:50.2440440 - [0002/1467]: Executing command: "alter index all on [dbo].[Affiliate] rebuild with (online = on);".
2023-06-06 07:39:50.2596849 - [0003/1467]: Executing command: "alter index all on [dbo].[template_step] rebuild with (online = on);".
2023-06-06 07:39:50.2753131 - [0004/1467]: Executing command: "alter index all on [dbo].[mapping_monthly] rebuild with (online = on);".
2023-06-06 07:39:50.7596876 - [0005/1467]: Executing command: "alter index all on [dbo].[statement] rebuild with (online = on);".
2023-06-06 07:39:50.7753120 - [0006/1467]: Executing command: "alter index all on [dbo].[history] rebuild with (online = on);".
2023-06-06 07:39:50.7753120 - [0007/1467]: Executing command: "alter index all on [dbo].[formula_items] rebuild with (online = on);".
2023-06-06 07:39:50.7909373 - [0008/1467]: Executing command: "alter index all on [dbo].[monthly_staging] rebuild with (online = on);".
2023-06-06 07:39:50.8221873 - [0009/1467]: Executing command: "alter index all on [dbo].[sales] rebuild with (online = on);".
Msg 121, Level 20, State 0, Line 82
A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.)

Completion time: 2023-06-06T15:21:35.2092836+02:00
```

I'm running the query from SSMS installed on a VM on Azure. Quite sure it cannot be connectivity problems. This happens 1 time out of 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The semaphore problem was caused by the connection cut form the VDI, on which I had SSMS, and the Azure SQL Database.

there is no point ot reinvent the wheel. Microsoft propose an out-of-the-box solution for Azure SQL Database: [Auto-shrink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/file-space-manage?view=azuresql#auto-shrink)

```
-- Enable auto-shrink for the current database.
ALTER DATABASE CURRENT SET AUTO_SHRINK ON;
```

[image]

This made the trick.

If you then want to rebuild the indexes, once again, there is no point to reinvent the wheel. Microsoft propose [Rebuilding SQL Database indexes using Azure Automation](https://geeks.ms/davidjrh/2015/10/08/rebuilding-sql-database-indexes-using-azure-automation/)